# Hide nabber when user clicks elsewhere on the page body

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

How would I hide this navbar when the user clicks anywhere else on the page (body) except on the navbar elements? Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and make the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[blur](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)" event is what you are most likely looking for. The implementation will change on the way you want to use it, but you can make it so that when someone clicks *off* of your taskbar it will hide, just like you said. Here is some pseudocode:

```
$("taskBar").blur(function(){
  $("taskBar).hide();
});
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_focus_blur) is also a good example of how it works!